# Can the Execute Package task execute a package stored in TFS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, tfs, ssis

I just added  a new folder and several packages to TFS server from source control, and they do exist when checking from source control.

However,  none of them could be found when I tried to build a Parent package and to locate those uploaded packages in SQL server. My operation is as follows:

```
  1. Add "Execute Package Task" component, then double click to edit
  2. Package Location: SQL Server;  
     Connection: XXXX;   
     Package Name: Here pops up a list of folders and package files but newly uploaded ones are not included.
```

"Connection" is filled correctly because old filefolders and packages (uploaded by other people) are listed in Package Name pop-up window.

So how could I configure my packages on TFS to make it shown from SQL Server package list?

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. As the documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137609%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> The Execute Package task can run packages stored in the SQL Server
>   msdb database and packages stored in the file system. The task uses an
>   OLE DB connection manager to connect to SQL Server and a File
>   connection manager to access the file system.

The Execute Package task has no idea what TFS is or how to connect to it. If you really needed to do this, then you would have to write your own [custom task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135965%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that does know how to connect to TFS.

However I have no idea why you want to execute packages directly from TFS anyway, it's a source control system (among other things), not a package repository.